# Database Translations Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, translation

I have problem with creating custom translator from database in ZF2. I have a DB like this [image]

and files:

1)Application/module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(),
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => function  (\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager)
            {
                $pluginManager = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\LoaderPluginManager();
                $pluginManager->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
                $pluginManager->setFactory('DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory', function($serviceManager)
                {
                    $translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory();
                    return $translator->createService($serviceManager);
                });
                $translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator(array());
                $translator->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
                $translator->setPluginManager($pluginManager);
                $translator->addRemoteTranslations('DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory');
                return $translator;
            },
    ),
),

'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\Database',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

2) Zend/I18n/Translator/Loader/Database.php

```
<?php

namespace Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Plural\Rule as PluralRule;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\TextDomain;


class Database implements RemoteLoaderInterface {

protected $dbAdapter;


public $dbAdapter;


public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter = null)
{
    if ($dbAdapter === null)
    {
        $configArray = array('driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'database' => 'dbname',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'pswd',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
        );
        $dbAdapter = new Adapter($configArray);
    }
    $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
}


public function load($locale, $textDomain)
{
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $select = $sql->select('ic_var')->columns(array('value'))
                  ->where(array('language' => $locale, 'name' => $textDomain));

    $messages = $this->dbAdapter->query(
        $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select),
        Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
    );

    $textDomain = new TextDomain();

    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        if (isset($textDomain[$message['name']])) {
            if (!is_array($textDomain[$message['name']])) {
                $textDomain[$message['name']] = array(
                    $message['plural_index'] => $textDomain[$message['name']]
                );
            }
            $textDomain[$message['name']][$message['plural_index']] = $message['value'];
        } else {
            $textDomain[$message['name']] = $message['value'];
        }
    }
    return $textDomain;
}
}
```

3) Zend/I18n/Translator/DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Zend\I18n\Translator;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\Database;

class DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new Database($serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
    }
}
```

4) Application/Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'DatabaseTranslationLoader',
        'text-domain',
        'text-domain'
    );
}
```

But translation doesn`t work, because db adapter not find in loader:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\I18n\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Specified loader is not a file loader'

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't define your custom classes in the `Zend` namespace as this is reserved a namespace for the ZF2 library and you don't want to touch (or add) files in the vendor directory.
Just put the custom classes in your own namespace outside the vendor folder. i.e. `MyI18n`

You can register you custom remote loader to the pluginManager in `module.config.php`.

```
return array(
    'translator' => array(
        'loaderpluginmanager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'database' => 'MyI18n\Translator\DatabaseTranslationLoaderFactory',
            )
        ),
        'remote_translation' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'database' //This sets the database loader for the default textDomain
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

You don't have to overwrite the Translator factory if you want to add a custom loader, so just remove that code in your `Module.php`.
Als remove the configuration under `translation_file_patterns` as this is only needed for file loaders.

**EDIT**

For the above to work you need to overwrite the `TranslatorServiceFactory` because ZF has no support to register custom loaders on the plugin manager.

```
namespace MyNamespace\Translator;

use Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory as BaseTranslatorFactory;

class TranslatorServiceFactory extends BaseTranslatorFactory
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return MvcTranslator
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $translator = parent::createService($serviceLocator);

        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $pluginManagerConfig = isset($config['translator']['loaderpluginmanager']) ? $config['translator']['loaderpluginmanager'] : array();
        $pluginManager = new LoaderPluginManager(new Config($pluginManagerConfig));
        $pluginManager->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
        $translator->setPluginManager($pluginManager);

        return $translator;
    }
}
```

Now register your custom factory in the service configuration:

```
class Module
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'MvcTranslator' => 'MyNamespace\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it, and got an error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\I18n\Translator\LoaderPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for database' in /home/thebigch/www/onlinecontest/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:518`

Comment: The configuration above is not ZF2 default but can only be achieved by overwriting the Translator factory. I forgot that when I initially answered the question. My answer included the related code now. I think a lot of users need to register custom loaders so I think something like this should be implemented in the ZF2 core. Maybe I find some spare time the next weeks to create a Pull Request.

Comment: Shouldn't the database translator be an instance of `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface`?

Comment: No the database translator should implement the interface  `Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\RemoteLoaderInterface`. You can implement the `TranslatorInterface` to write you own custom translator, but there is no need to. You'll end up rewriting all the logic for fallback locales, caching, events etc.

Comment: Ah okay, I seem to be getting this error: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\View\Helper\HeadTitle::setTranslator() must be an instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface, instance of Core\I18n\Translator\Loader\DatabaseTranslator given, called in ~/Sites/zend/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php on line 157 and defined in ~/Sites/zend/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadTitle.php on line 188` and can't seem to get the above example working.

Answer (score 0):

I register custom remote loader to the pluginManager in module.config.php like this

```
'translator' => [
    'loaderpluginmanager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'database' => function($lpm){
                $sm = $lpm->getServiceLocator();
                $loader = new Zf2Translation\Loader\DatabaseTranslationLoader($sm);
                return $loader;
            },
        ],
    ],
    'remote_translation' => [
        [
            'type' => 'database', 
        ],
    ],
]
```

Next in Database Loader class

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\RemoteLoaderInterface;
class DatabaseTranslationLoader implements RemoteLoaderInterface
{
    protected $dbAdapter;
    protected $sm;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
        $this->dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.